# "npm install" on react app shows deprecateds warnings

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, deprecated

If I delete the folder `node_modules` and try to recreate it using `npm install`, I get lot of deprecated warnings. Attached all warning messages.

The problem is not related to a specific computer, I tried on several computers, and also installed the latest versions of Node and Visual Studio Code (node-v18.16.0-x64, VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.78.2). It is not related to a specific app, but also when creating a new app using: `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Is the problem that `npx create-react-app my-app` itself has become deprecated? If so, how to recreate `node_modules` folder for old apps created using `npx create-react-app my-app`. If not, how to fix the problem?

The warning messages:

```
> npm install
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1495 packages, and audited 1496 packages in 1m

234 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: the warning is about the packages being on the old versions. few solutions: 1st (recommended) STOP using react create app. its old and garbage. instead create ur own stack. now if you are learning - sure might be alright. but if u are doing any important work - drop it. 2 nd. update the packages. that's it :D. 3rd ignore it.

Comment: @Lith I'm learning, so I don't mind trying. It's not related to my code, because it also happens when I create a new app. I heard it is not recommended using `npx create-react-app my-app`. Is it because it deprecated itself? Am I right? Is this the cause of the above problem? If so, I'd love to know how to fix apps I've previously created like this.

Comment: create-react-app - it creates and set up the base of a project. it installs and configured required packages etc. By itself that's what is it - just a bundle of packages and configs. It's there to easily create a react app from nothing so you wouldn't have to learn webpack, packages routing, etc all kinds of stuff before even setting up a project. so for learning - it's great. But since it's a bundle of packages (libraries) - it's not updated that often. hence some of the libraries in the bundle are old versions (part 1)

Comment: so to fix those warnings all you need to do is update the packages (libraries) and those warnings will go away. (part 2)

Comment: but in general you shouldint worry about those warnings. You might not get the up to date package usage, some docs might not work since the libs are out of date but the main focus on react and react logic will remain. The only time you want to worry about package warnings when you are creating actually apps for publishing but not when learning (part 3)

Comment: In general, people create their own projects using packages instead of create-react-app. That way you can get what you want and remove all the not required stuff (packages). that will decrease the bloat that create-react-app brings in (and that's a lot) so the performance is better. But right now if you are just learning react - either update the packages OR ignore the warnings. To update the packages - simply run `npm update` (part 4)

Comment: I uninstalled the old version and installed the latest new version of Node.js, I ran `npm update`, checked `npm outdated` and all the packages are up to date. The warnings still keep appearing, even if it's a new project created using `npx create-react-app my-app`, with an updated package.json, whenever I delete its node_modules and try to recreate it using `npm install`.

Comment: deleting node_modules will do nothing. thats not how packaging works. You have 2 files - package.json and package-lock.json. package.json describes your installed packages while a package-lock.json is full instructions of your packages + package dependencies. that's right, some packages depend on other packages hence installing 1 will install others. and sometimes the package will depend on some other package that could be outdated. So if you updated all the packages in package.json yet some dependency packages show as outdated - nothing can be done (part 1)

Comment: You could manually update them but you shouldn't cuz the package that it depends on could break if the dependency package had some critical/major changes. so that case just ignore it. and never NEVER manually edit package-lock.json (part 2)

Answer (score 0):

No, npx-create-next-app has not become deprecated. The warning messages clearly state that it is stable@0.1.8, rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2, sourcemap-codec@1.4.8, w3c-hr-time@1.0.2, workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0, and svgo@1.3.2 that are deprecated. To fix it, go through your code, find where you are importing the deprecated packages, and replace them with the later versions suggested by the error messages.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (I fixed the question). I meant maybe the problem is happening because I created the app using `npx create-react-app my-app` that is maybe deprecated? In any case, the problem is not in my code, because it also happens to me in a new application that I create like this.

Comment: I just used npx create-react-app yesterday and it worked fine for me.